# linux 22.04 | linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (files locked

Tags: apt, upgrade, permissions, 22.04, linux-headers

I haven't used my pc in a while and when i logged on to update games and such I ran into an error with the linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04. i seem to have the (5.15.0.35.38 version) but need to be at (5.15.0.35.43 version). I proceeded to run the following command: [apt --fix-broken install], but it didn't work. It also says that files are locked and, as of now there are 13 permissions that were denied. If anyone knows how to fix this then thanks.

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and post the output to your question. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: I believe I had ran that command, don't remember the output sadly but I am happy to say that I just got the newer version and the only problems I have now are w/ snap/snapstore saying that there are no updates which you just simply just have to refresh the store